# Display file right in notepad++ on linux redhat el7

Tags: notepad++, rhel7, rights

in our company our source code is stored on a linux redhat el7 machine. If i want to open files with vi, a readonly file is displayed as readonly, but if i use notepad++ through windows explorer with this file, it shows, that it is writable. On the backup system (linux redhat el6) everything is working fine.

What could be the reason for this and how can we solved it?

If you need more information, please ask. I don't know, if this information is enough.

Kind regards

Comment: Actually, I have a question -- Is anything different about the file in linux redhat el7? If it's working in el6, then it is possible that the transfer between machines is corrupting it. Could you provide more exact info? File extension, etc.?

Comment: It is independent of the file extension. At the beginning, we used a backup process to copy all files from el6 to el7 machine. Now the process is vice versa. The problem only exists, if i open a file through windows explorer, in linux everything is correct.

Comment: Hmm.... So, it works on el6, yeah? Sooo.... That probably means something's wrong with el7.. Could you provide more info on the matter? :)

Comment: Sorry, i'm not really experienced in that case. I don't know, what kind of information is usefull at all. Please guide me, if it is possible.

Comment: Hmm. It sounds like something may be wrong with Windows Explore on el7. From the information you gave me, Windows Explorer won't display it as ReadOnly, right? Then I'd suggest uninstalling it then reinstalling it. If that doesn't work, come straight back :)

Comment: I just found something: If i open a file with Vim editor in Windows Explorer, the rights are displayed correctly on el7.

Comment: ...So does that mean your problem is solved? Or do you need more help? I'm here if you need me :)